# need help an exit statement in C programming

Tags: c, exit

This my code. It lets the user input number and then outputs it into a 32 bit binary number. The problem that I'm facing is that I need to find a way so that it keeps asking you for number after the input until "9999" is entered where it ends the program (not "press any key to continue")

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void db(unsigned int value);
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x;//
    printf("%s", "Enter in number:"); 
    scanf_s("%d", &x);//%u=unsinged number,, pointer
    db(x);
}//end of main

void db(unsigned int value)
{
   .........................
        }
```

Comment: Please, please, please, use indentation!

Comment: C code filenames should end in .c, not .cpp.

Comment: Sounds like homework, so I'll refrain from giving you a solution. But here's a hint: you want to wrap up the print/scanf/display bit within a `while` loop break out of the loop when "9999" is entered.

Comment: it was homework but i made the code, adding the while loop was just needed for extra marks which i got thanks to you guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a loop to your `main`, like this:

```
for (;;) {
    unsigned int x;// You may need to move this declaration to outside the loop
    printf("%s", "Enter in your student number:"); 
    scanf_s("%d", &x);//%u=unsinged number,, pointer
    if (x == 9999) break;
    displayBits(x);
}
```

Since the decision to continue or to stop is made in the middle of the loop's body, using a "forever" loop is preferred. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but since the `for (;;)` is the one described in K&R, I recommend using it over other alternatives.

Comment: @Wug That's OK, no problem :) SO's randomly jumping posts make me click a wrong link sometimes.

Comment: Especially because pre-your-edit, both answers were a short introductory statement followed by a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s", "Enter in your student number:"); 
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        if (x == 9999) break;
        else displayBits(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, `puts("\n");` prints 2 new lines since it prints a newline anyway.  To print just one new line, use `puts("");`

Comment: thanks guys i know it took a while to get back to say thanks, really dont know much this helped me